# Django page not found 404

Tags: python, django

i get this error while i am trying to run my django server and i am getting the following error  I don't know why

[image]

and the urls file is in the myproject/test/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url, include
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
url(r'', include('wars.urls')),
]
```

myproject/test/settings.py

```
ROOT_URLCONF = 'test.urls'

  TEMPLATES = [
      {
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [],
    'APP_DIRS': True,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
        ],
    },
},
  ]
```

in the same folder I have another folder wars which has the urls too , in myproject/wars/ursl.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views


urlpatterns = [
url(r'^auth/$', views.authenticate_for_token, name='authenticate'),

url(r'^records/all/(?P<token>[1-9]_[a-z]*)/$', views.records_list_all, name='records_all'),
url(r'^records/(?P<offset>[0-9]*)/(?P<limit>[1-9][0-9]*)/(?P<token>[1-9]_[a-z]*)/(?P<comp_code>[0-9]{2,8})/$', views.records_list_subset, name='records_all'),
url(r'^records/save/$', views.records_save, name='records_save'),

url(r'^dropdown/(?P<comp_code>[0-9]{2,8})/(?P<token>[1-9]_[a-z]*)/$', views.get_dropdown_lists, name='dropdown_lists'),

url(r'^approve/$', views.approve_category, name='approve_category'),
url(r'^approve/delete/$', views.approve_category_delete, name='approve_category_delete'),

url(r'^hide-sheet/$', views.hide_sheet, name='hide_sheet'),
url(r'^hide-sheet/delete/$', views.hide_sheet_delete, name='hide_sheet_delete'),


url(r'^template/download/$', views.template_download, name='template_download'),
url(r'^template/upload/$', views.template_upload, name='template_upload'),

url(r'^overview/$', views.Overview.as_view(), name='admin_overview'),

url(r'^login/$', views.LoginView.as_view(), name='login'),
url(r'^logout/$', views.logout_func, name='logout'),
url(r'^user/$', views.UserManagement.as_view(), name='user_mgmt'),
url(r'^user/upsert/$', views.user_create, name='user_create'),

url(r'^debug/$', views.debug_func, name='debug'),

]
```

I am trying to figure out the problem. it seems that i cant reach the page. and in the python server it says 
**Not Found: /
[27/Nov/2017 09:44:54] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 404 5189**

Comment: You don't have a page at that url

Comment: @Sayse what do u mean ?

Comment: I mean none of your urls point to that url

Comment: @Sayse because i want it directly to open at http://127.0.0.1:8005/
thats why i have
url(r'', include('wars.urls')),

Answer (score 1):

You don't have any regex pointing to `/` url path. You can change your overview view's URL like this

```
url(r'^overview/$', views.Overview.as_view(), name='admin_overview'),
```

to

```
url(r'^/$', views.Overview.as_view(), name='admin_overview'),
```

You will see the overview page available in `localhost:8005`.

Answer (score 0):

In `myproject/wars/ursl.py` add a URL pattern to `urlpatterns` to match the '/' case and implement the function, e.g.:

```
urlpatterns = [
# ... others
url(r'^debug/$', views.debug_func, name='debug'),
url(r'^/$', views.index, name='index'),
]
```

don't forget to implement `views.index` function or replace it with something else like `views.Overview.as_view()`.